# MvvmCross REST services architecture

Tags: rest, service, architecture, mvvmcross, crud

I have scenario similar to mvvmcross tutorial implementation on github. I do have this *BaseViewModel*.

```
public class BaseViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    protected void GeneralAsyncLoad(string url, Action<Stream> responseStreamHandler)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.BeginGetResponse((result) => GeneralProcessResponse(request, result, responseStreamHandler), null);     
    }
    protected void GeneralRequestSendObjectAsync<T>(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult, T objectToSend, Action<Stream> responseStreamHandler)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        using (var requestStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, objectToSend);
            requestStream.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);
        }
        request.BeginGetResponse(result => GeneralProcessResponse(request, result, responseStreamHandler), request);    
    }
    private void GeneralProcessResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result, Action<Stream> responseStreamHandler)
    {
        var response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            responseStreamHandler(stream);
        }       
    }   
}
```

This class is used to be inherited. Inherited classes use this pattern to call the rest services. For example *TestListViewModel*.

```
public class TestListViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    /* Some code here */
    public TestListViewModel()
    {
        AsyncLoad();
    }
    private void AsyncLoad()
    {
        GeneralAsyncLoad(URL_TESTLIST, ProcessResponse);
    }
    private void ProcessResponse(Stream stream)
    {
        var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<TestDataViewModel>));
        var tlist = (List<TestDataViewModel>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);

        List = tlist;
    }

    public MvxCommand<int> DeleteCommand
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand<int>(DoDelete, i => i > 0); }
    }
    private async void DoDelete(int asTestID)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(URL_TESTDELETE);
        request.Method = "DELETE";

        var asyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);
        request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

        AsyncLoad();
    }
}
```

And all this is working just fine, but I am not satisfied with it. Is there any better solution to using REST services with mvvmcross?
Recently I read an article of mvvmcross plugins (Network plugin), but i didn't find any examples online.
Is there any nugget package to be downloaded or should I program my own implementation of *IMvxRestClient* and *IMvxJsonRestClient*  ?
**My intention at the end is to decouple data access functions from implementation.**

Comment: THere are some examples of the plugin in the wiki - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#network - alternatively many more libraries now support PCL - e.g. HttpClient, Json.Net, RestSharp, etc

Comment: @Stuart, I peeked the code of N-06 and extended the code from SimpleRestService. I read the plugin article in the wiki but could not find a particular example where **network** is implemented.